# C method returning NSString gives 'implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC' error

Tags: objective-c

I have this `C` method:

.h

```
NSString *NSStringFromMKMapPoint(MKMapPoint mapPoint);
```

.m

```
NSString *NSStringFromMKMapPoint(MKMapPoint mapPoint) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i,%i", (int)mapPoint.x, (int)mapPoint.y];
}
```

Trying to set an NSString using the return value, as so:

```
NSString *tilePointString = NSStringFromMKMapPoint(tilePoint);
```

is giving me this error:

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC

Comment: Show how this function (not method) is called.

Comment: Exactly which line is giving you the error?

Comment: Also, is the function and the caller in two different files? If so, is the function declared in some .h file? Does the declaration have the same signature as the implementation?

Comment: Yes. Declared in a .h file, implemented in a .m file, with the same signature.

Comment: And properly included where you use it? It really smells like a default return type issue.

Comment: Why do you have a C function instead of an Objective-C method?

Comment: Because its implemented to follow the regular NSString conversion pattern - `NSStringFromCGSize()`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've failed to `#include` or `#import` the header file that declares the method in the file in which you're calling it. Without a function declaration, C (and presumably Objective-C) will default to `int` as the return type. That would explain your error on this line:

```
NSString *tilePointString = NSStringFromMKMapPoint(tilePoint);
```

I think the compiler here is assuming a return type of `int`, and then complaining that it can't convert `int` to `NSString*` in the assignment.

So, check the file(s) where you're calling this function and make sure that you've imported the header file that declares the function.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that it recognised the method lead me to believe it was imported, as I thought it was. If it wasn't a suggestion, my first port of call would've been to check the import.